# What's the difference between a regular js int and one from jquery.val()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a script called [countUp.js](https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/) which basically increments an integer in an animated way until it reaches it's desired amount.

Here is my code:

### HTML:

```
<h2 id="countUp-1">2500</h2>
```

### JS

```
var theval = 5000;
var demo = new CountUp("countUp-1", 0, theval, 0, 2.5);
demo.start();
```

This successfully animates my counter from 0 to 5000. Perfect.

But what I want to do is animate the value already in the h2 tag (2500). So I tried this.

```
var theval = parseInt($('#countUp-1').val());
var demo = new CountUp("countUp-1", 0, theval, 0, 2.5);
demo.start();
```

But with this I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: c.match is not a function"

How could this be? I'm just sending an int to the CountUp function in both cases?

Set up a fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/0yawm9jr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('countUp-1').val()` doesn't exist (there is no `value` attribute on your specific element). Try this (see the [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yawm9jr/2/)):

```
var theval = 5000;
var demo = new CountUp("countUp-1", 0, theval, 0, 2.5);
demo.start();

var theval2 = parseInt($('#countUp-2').html().split(',').join(''));
var demo2 = new CountUp("countUp-2", 0, theval2, 0, 2.5);
demo2.start();
```

The jQuery method `.val()` retrieves the contents of the `value` attribute of an element. In your case, you're just using an HTML element with an `innerHTML` set to your value. Therefore, you need to call `$(yourElement).html()`.

Also, your number contains commas, so we need to split the number at the commas an rejoin it with no non-numerical characters.

Comment: @user2864740, yeah good clarification thank you. I've updated my answer to reflect that.